# sorted array not showing values correctly

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, arrays

I have an array which contains distances between current user location and some annotation pins. Although the first log shows the values correctly, when I add them in an array all the values are "0". What am I doing wrong? I already referred to apple documentation. I get NO errors what so ever. Thank you in advance..

```
 for (Posts *post in allPosts) {
    CLLocation *postLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:post.coordinate.latitude longitude:post.coordinate.longitude];

    CLLocation *userLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:appDelegate.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:appDelegate.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    CLLocationDistance dist = [userLoc distanceFromLocation:postLocation];
    distance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", dist];


    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:post, nil];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:distance ascending:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@", sort);
    NSArray *sor = @[sort];
    NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sor];



    float flo = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sorted]floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%.f",flo);
```

Comment: Please edit your code to show the actual code you're using.

Comment: You've got several things wrong here -- you instantiate a new array every time through the loop and then put one object, post, into it and try to sort that one object. This is in addition to the problem that @Eiko mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
float flo = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sorted]floatValue];
NSLog(@"%.f",flo);
```

You are trying to put an array into an string, then using it's float value. You probably want to take an element of the array instead.

Comment: so what is the better way to extract the float value from the array? can you give me some sample code?

Comment: I don't know what your array look like, but it makes no sense to cast an array to a float. Maybe it's sorted[0], or sorted[1], ...

Comment: sorry, I am new to obj-c.. what I am trying to do is to take the distances between current user location and all annotations and sort them so I can find the nearest one from the user location. the CLLocationDistance is in float and for the sortDescriptorWithKey I need a string. So I have to translate the float to string and then back to float in a new array. I searched the web and I couldn't find a better way to do this.. Even in apple's doc's it says that this is the way or a custom comparison (selector). What is the better approach? thank you once again..

Comment: @user1780591, is your goal just to find the post object whose location is closest to the current location? If so, then you don't really even want to do an array sort, you want to use indexOfObjectPassingTest: on allPosts.

Comment: the problem is that these distance have to refresh each time the locationManager is called. The distances are fine but once the user location is changed the sorting gets messed up. i.e. when app is launched the sorting is fine, but then it retains the array's structure (list) and adjusting the "new locations" not in a sorting list.